# Magento: custom module layout override not working

Tags: php, xml, magento, layout

I have a small custom module which is supposed to show on all product pages, but it doesn't. It only shows when setting its reference to "content", but I want it to display witin the already existing product view divs, thus, display it within the "product.info" reference.

Here's my code:

**app/design/frontend/default/company/layout/company/socialbuttons.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout>
  <catalog_product_view>
    <reference name="product.info">
     <block type="core/template" name="company_socialbuttons" template="company/socialbuttons.phtml" />
</reference>
  </catalog_product_view>
</layout>
```

I've spent hours finding the error, without success and if I can't find a solution soon I will do it the ugly way (calling the phtml inside the parent phtml). What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`product.info` handle is an instance of `catalog/product_view` block, and `content` is an instance of `core/text_list` block. The latter block is rendering every child block, even if there is no call to `getChildHtml()` method in the template.

So, if you want to add your block to `product.info`, you should call `getChildHtml()` method in the template.

Or, you can try reference of another blocks in `product.info` block: `alert.urls` or `product.info.extrahint`

Comment: Great, the module is now displaying when referencing alert.urls (or product.info.extrahint). Just one more question: Is there a way to change the position of the alert.urls block via local.xml, without moving the getChildHtml('alert_urls') call in view.phtml?

Comment: @Socrates - Why would you want to use the alert.urls block for something completely different (social media buttons) just to avoid using a getChildHtml call.  Wouldn't you rather the code was well written and structured?

Comment: @Socrates unfortunately, it's impossible to move alert_urls block using local.xml

Comment: @Drew I used product.alerts because I found no other way of making it show up inside the desired div. I tried it by calling my custom block core/template block but it never showed up inside the desired block.

Comment: @WebFlakeStudio Thanks for your help, I already noted your website and email, as I might have some more complicated work in the future :-)

Answer (score 1):

If directly referencing the product.info block then you will have to use a call to getChildHtml() in your product view template:

`echo $this->getChildHtml('company_socialbuttons');`